# How to sort a map with its maximum value of key in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort a map with definition `map<double,deque<Object>>`
with the maximum value of double (key) but by default the map takes the minimum value of key . How can I sort the map by the maximum value of key which is a double .

Thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING:** you should most probably **NOT** use `double` (or any other floating point format) as a **key**. Loss of precisions will often result in two seemingly identical computations producing slightly different results when executed in floating point... this issue can be somewhat tamed by providing a custom comparator tailored for the precision-loss at hand, but be aware it's hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't re-sort a map, but you can use a map that sorts itself in the reverse order to the default. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) has a third template parameter for the comparison functor used for ordering. The default is `std::less<key_type>`. You can trivially use the reverse ordering by using `std::greater<key_type>`:

```
std::map<double, std::deque<Object>, std::greater<double>> m;
```

The closest you can come to sorting a map is to create a new one based on an original with different sorting criteria:

```
std::map<double, std::deque<Object>> orig = ....;
std::map<double, std::deque<Object>, std::greater<double>> m(orig.begin, orig.end());
```

Comment: Greater is what I wanted . Thank you very much

Comment: what if I want to set another map with smaller values , this is because I am using reverse iterator in second map

Answer (score 0):

map is a key-value pair, key has to be unique in general, if not then value type could be a vector or list instead of a single typed elemental value like hash_map> where MyType is struct or a class. While querying you search with the key to retrieve the value, no notion of sorting. Otherwise, you need to use a vector instead.